# Saving excel file in datastore

Tags: google-app-engine

How to save a excel file in the datastore(not content of file) in google apps using java?

Comment: What's the difference between a file and its contents? What language are you using? And I presume you do mean App Engine, not Google Apps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [bulkloader](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata.html) which enables you to download the data as a csv file which Excel can handle.